# Batch file that takes the file for the previous day only and copy it elsewhere

Tags: scripting, batch-file, copy

OK, so I've done a bit of research but have hit a bit of a hurdle here. What I'm trying to do is, (using event scheduler), run a batch daily, that takes the "ips*.csv file (* is just the date format) for the previous day only and copy it elsewhere, for my test I used "destiny ips" folder. I think I've messed up on the last hurdle.

```
 FORFILES /P "C:\Users\J\Desktop\ips bat\source ips" /M "ips*.csv" /C "cmd /c XCOPY C:\Users     \J\Desktop\ips bat\source ips folder C:\Users\J\Desktop\ips bat\destiny ips" /D -1
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (
 'dir /b /o:-d "c:\users...etc...ips*.csv" ' ) do (
 xcopy /d "%%i" "C:\Users\J\Desktop\ips bat\destiny ips\" &goto :eof
 )
```

should do this very simply (in fact, it can all be on the one line) It will copy only the very latest version of the file to the destination - and then only if the destination file does not already exist (or is different from the version in source.) This should take care of any non-operational days like weekends or public holidays.

If the destination keeps ALL of the history (ie. there may be `ips*.csv` files in the destination that are not in the source, but not vice-versa (other than the new one for "yesterday") ) then simply

```
xcopy /d "c:\users...etc...ips*.csv" "C:\Users\J\Desktop\ips bat\destiny ips\"
```

will suffice.

The critical points are:

1. the destination ends in "\" to say 'this is a directory name'
2. the /d which will tell XCOPY to copy only new or updated files.

(It stands to reason that ...etc... is the remainder of the pathname required - DOS is not psychic)

Comment: Really helpful that, seriously thanks a lot. 

Can't see /D in help (eg. /?)

Thought I may have been overcomplicating it! one issue i have is that I don't want todays, even though it will be there being written to. Just previous days (once complete).

Answer (score 1):

To include special characters in the command line, use the hex code for the character in 0xHH format (ex. 0x09 is theTAB character, 0x22 is the double quote " character.) so "C:\Program Files\" becomes ^0x22C:\Program^ Files\^0x22

```
FORFILES 
   /P "C:\Users\J\Desktop\ips bat\source ips" 
   /M "ips*.csv" 
   /C "cmd /c 
     XCOPY ^0x22C:\Users\J\Desktop\ips^ bat\source ips folder^0x22
           ^0x22C:\Users\J\Desktop\ips^ bat\destiny ips^0x22" 
   /D -1
```

I have separated it onto multi-lines for readability, but you will want to put that back into one line.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, sorry, I can't seem to get that to work, possibly mislead you. My issues isn't the double quotes, my file doesn't have them. My issue is that I can't seem to get the logic to work.

I can't seem to get JUST the previous day and I can't seem to get the files copied over.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspect-:

```
 XCOPY C:\Users     \J\Desktop\ips bat\source
```

Is it correct?